# Inverse Energy Cascade in 2D turbulence

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence

If the production term in the Turbulent Kinetic Energy (TKE) budget equation is negative, it implies that energy is transferred from the turbulent flow field to the mean flow field. Does this imply an inverse energy cascade?